# Application that must reside in specific dir and with dependency with relative path dependency

Tags: .net, dll, dllimport

My DLL (a.dll) depends on another DLL (b.dll, third party) that has a relative path to an exe (app.exe) such that both a.dll and b.dll must live in the same directory as app.exe. However, I need a.dll to live elsewhere because it is loaded by another exe that only searches in a particular directory. If a.dll lives anywhere else than where b.dll and app.exe live, and I include a reference to b.dll, then I get a 'file not found' error referring to app.exe. Thus, it appears the path of the invoking thread is the one used for a relative path to app.exe.

(b.dll is used to drive app.exe, which is a proprietary application that talks to some robotics in a closed-source language. I cannot change this.)

Is it possible to handle this in any way besides making a server that lives where app.exe lives and that communicates with my code from where it needs to live? For example, is it possible to essentially change the working directory of the imported b.dll?

Comment: Maybe. Without knowing the precise details it is hard to say more. Do you know any more than what you say here?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan added some more info. Any specific areas that would help to clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Without any code, or knowledge of why this constraint is enforced, it's hard to help

Comment: Essentially, nobody can tell you how to change the behaviour without knowledge of the mechanism behind the current behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to change to the current directory to where app.exe resides.